# MySQL Online Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql

Can anyone suggest a good online free MySQL database. I've tried four till now:

[db4free](http://www.db4free.net/) [FreeMySQL](http://www.freemysql.net/) onPhP 000webhost

Either of them gave me an timeout error on my connect file or actively restricted connection to it, meaning the host won't allow a remote connection to the database.

If there isn't any good online database can I create my own server using my computer, since it gets rarely turned off and when my server is offline I could return an error message saying that the server is currently offline.
My final objective is to have a simple comment box for a webpage. Witch I believe it won't need a massive data storage with 3 columns (id, name, comment)

NOTE: Can't post more then two links yet.

Comment: Hosting via your home broadband is considered less reliable than using those in data centers since ISP's generally have more downtime. Even the most stable connections can have no internet for X seconds and still retain a sync with their exchange because they haven't timed out. Unless you have a low contention line with a SLA agreement I do not recommend hosting at home.

Comment: Also most free SQL providers have limits such as database size and request limit.. if its a small database and not many requests per a day then I recommend http://xeround.com/

Comment: As with most things, when it comes to web hosting you get what you pay for. Even $5/mo will get you infinitely better reliability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to try https://hostzil.la

> They provide :

1. Free CLOUD hosting
2. Upto 100 mb diskspace
3. UNLIMITED bandwidth,database, etc.
4. Low downtime.
5. High speed servers.

> I Recommend you to try it. They are new but i host there for months and i dont have any sort of problems.
>   **My website loads faster(*max load time:734ms*)** . You can find your website load time @ [tools.pingdom.com](http://tools.pingdom.com)

Regards Venkat,
Happy hosting.

> And Running Own server cause many problems(your computer cannot take the traffic) as hosting companies will have equiments loaded to hold high traffic and also you require high speed internet connection(special plans provided by your isp).

Comment: I'll give it a try, I hope it has MySQL database and that allows me to remotely access them trough PhP

Answer (score 2):

Here is several free relational database service.

http://aws.amazon.com/free/

"To help new AWS customers get started in the cloud, AWS is introducing a free usage tier. The free tier can be used for anything you want to run in the cloud: launch new applications, test existing applications in the cloud, or simply gain hands-on experience with AWS.
"

But the service i've register is xeround.com which give you free 10 mb of db storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you need MySQL Database provider 
Have a look at database as a service providers

> http://xeround.com/
>
> https://cloudant.com/

or you can use the amazon RDS Free

Answer (score 0):

@marian The first question I would ask is: what is your use case?

If you are just wanting to fire up a MySQL instance to test every now and then, you can fire up a local one on your laptop/desktop. Either bare metal or in a small virtual machine.

I'll address other "always online" solutions:

**Serving From Home**

This can work. However, you have to realize that you are opening yourself up to being hacked/attacked. This could also be a violation of your ISP's TOS/EULA.

A safe way of implementing this is having an intermediate trusted host that you can establish a tunnel to, from the box at home.

Ie, something like:

```
ssh -R3306:localhost:3306 tunnel-user@trusted-host.domain.com keep-alive-script
```

Then, from the trusted host, you can connect to the host via:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p -h localhost
```

And be able to connect to the box from the trusted host. This allows you to host from home without the risk of having any public facing open ports at home.

**Serving From a Generous Friend's Box**

If serving from home doesn't work, or you need a bit more reliability, find a good friend who also has hosting capacity and beg/borrow some space/cycles to implement your mysql instance.

**Spend Some Money**

Depending on your MySQL needs, you can get a small instance from various online VPS hosting providers. However, it won't be free. It CAN be cheap. To the tune of maybe $6/month if you go with an annual plan.  See http://prgmr.com/xen/

**Go With Amazon RDS**

They have some free tier offers. Haven't tried them, but definitely an option. If get charged only after you exceed the transaction limits/cap, then you effectively have it for free.

I would avoid the free MySQL services out there. You lose too much control and depending on the data you will be hosting on the instance, poses a risk to your sensitive data.